# Multiple datacenter replication and local quorum?

Tags: cockroachdb

I created a cluster from 6 nodes.
3 nodes in Eu west1 and 3 nodes in EU west2 
I set the locality for every group of nodes like : --locality=region=europe,datacenter=west1
I also set the replica to 6 to have all ranges and all data  on every node. 
What will happen if the connection between data centers is lost the whole cluster goes down ?
I tried to kill 3 nodes in one of the datacenters and cluster is not operational because the majority of the nodes are down and quorum is less that 4.
Is it possible to make the 2 datacentes to work with their local quorum 2/3

I also  played a bit with replications settings and sometimes cluster is healthy if I kill 3 nodes from 6 and was I was able to write to the cluster. Sometimes I can only read from the cluster. Cluster is working with replica of 5 and 3 nodes killed from 6. Still paying with this but if someone can give me more information will be very helpful.

To be able to replicate across datacentes is very cool feature but if I lost the whole cluster when one of the datacenters is down ruin the whole good idea at least for me.

Answer (score 2):

CockroachDB requires a *majority* of replicas to be fully operational, which means `> half`, not `>= half`. In order to survive the loss of a full datacenter or region, you must have *three* DCs/regions, not two. Try running two nodes in each of three regions instead of three nodes in two regions.

> Is it possible to make the 2 datacenters to work with their local quorum 2/3

Not for a single table (because it would be impossible to guarantee consistency if each datacenter were able to act in isolation from the other). You've configured the data to be replicated across all six replicas, which means four replicas are required to make a quorum. If you want each datacenter to be able to operate independently of the other, you would need two separate tables, with each one configured to be located within one of the datacenters.

Comment: The formula is `(n - 1)/2`, where `n` is the number of nodes.  As long as the number is 0 or higher, the cluster survives.  And, the higher the number the better!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer just to clear few thing. But looks like you got my point and what I want to accomplish.
But as far as I understand if I have  2x3 node in 2 different DC's if one DC goes down. I have 3 live nodes for the quorum I need at least 4 . N/2 +1.
So if I have 3x3 I can lost one DC because if I have 2 DC's live I will have a quorum .
And one last question if I don't set replication to 9 if I loose 3 nodes some in one DC some  ranges will be not available right ?